# Most Recent Email Automatically Selected When Viewing Folder - NOT Ideal

Tags: microsoft-outlook

There is this annoying issue where when viewing different emails in different folders where the most recent email is automatically selected and when I click away it marks the message as "read". I find this very annoying because sometimes I leave messages marked as "unread" on purpose and just open that folder to see which emails have been routed to that folder via my Microsoft Outlook Rules.

I was wondering if there was a way to ensure that I can view a folder without it selecting an email automatically. Ideally, I would like to open the folder and THEN click an email if I want to open it.

Answer (score 1):

Open Outlook,  View Tab. Select Reading Pan and then Reading Pane Options.  Uncheck Mark as Read.

Then when you select an email header in the Reading Pane (regular working view) the email will not be marked as Read.

That is the only setting that affect what you are seeing.

[image: Outlook Mark as Read]

Answer (score 0):

If your main concern is just the read/unread status of the top item, agree with John that you can modify the Reading Pane Options to prevent items from being automatically marked as read：
[image]

If you still want to stop the most recent item being selected, as far as I know currently there's no option for it. You can send your idea to the dedicated feedback portal for MS outlook via: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/89a8afa3-2e1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472

Comment: Thank you! I still want to have items marked as read in general when I click on it and go to different emails, just not when I open a particular folder immediately.

Comment: But it's currently not possible to have it both ways. So... just submit your feedback into the aforementioned official link.

Or you can uncheck "Mark item as read when selection changes" and select "Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane" but adjust the time period to a bit longer like 10 seconds. In this way, an item can be automatically marked as read when you click on it and view it for more than 10 seconds.